# Bundle (or rake, or rails) pretends to use the system version of Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an old ruby installed in my Linux system:

```
% ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p188 (2011-03-28) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

I have a newer ruby installed in my home directory:

```
% ~/ruby/bin/ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
```

But somehow bundler (or rake, or rails) runs the old ruby on some step and gets:

```
% ~/ruby/bin/bundle exec rake

Rails 4 prefers to run on Ruby 2.0.

You're running
  ruby 1.9.2p188 (2011-03-28) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Please upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3 or newer to continue.
```

Why? What do I do?

Here is what it does under the hood:

```
% strace -f -e trace=process ~/ruby/bin/bundle exec rake
execve("/home/ilyak/ruby/bin/bundle", ["/home/ilyak/ruby/bin/bundle", "exec", "rake"], [/* 32 vars */]) = 0
clone(Process 6460 attached
child_stack=0x7ffeb759cff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7ffeb759d9d0, tls=0x7ffeb759d700, child_tidptr=0x7ffeb759d9d0) = 6460
[pid  6460] _exit(0)                    = ?
[pid  6460] +++ exited with 0 +++
execve("/usr/bin/rake", ["rake"], [/* 37 vars */]) = 0
```

Why? What were they thinking?

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is

```
export PATH=/home/ilyak/ruby/bin:$PATH
```

but obviously it's not cool.

Comment: What's wrong with that? When you run bundle or any executable script, your system looks at the `#!` line at the top of the script file to figure out what command to run. You can see that by running `head -n 1 $(which bundle)`. Most likely it contains something like `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` that searches your path for the `ruby` command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on here, but would recommend you remove all trace of your rubies and start fresh using a ruby version manager such as rvm, rbenv, or chruby. (I'd recommend chruby: https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) This should straighten out your multiple versions of ruby and avoid the issue in the first place.

Comment: I've tried RVM but it doesn't seem to support my obscure distro, so I guess I stick to PATH manipulations :-/